# Cannot use the package "icon" in RStudio

Tags: r

When I try to install the package, it appears:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘icon’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Comment: Please see specifically the sections entitled "1. You can't spell" (sorry I didn't come up with the name) and "6. The package is out of date".

Comment: Note that package names are case sensitive. It seems like there was a package named ICON but [it has been removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ICON/index.html) because the authors did not make updates for the latest version of R.